# Microsoft Clarity: screen recording pauses when there is inactivity

Tags: recording, clarity

I faced up with the strange bug in screen recording tab. When timeline goes to the inactivity state marker the recording sticks. The record starts playing only if I manually click on the timeline after the inactivity state marker. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

I tried turn off the "skip inactivity" checkbox